# Regex - Capturing conditional group

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I am trying to convert MD syntax to HTML in Java.

On https://regex101.com/ I am trying to match this:

`\[(.*)\]\((.*) \"(icon|small|medium|big)?\"\)`

regex to these test lines:

```
[link 1](https://aka.ms/aadrecoverykey "icon")
[link 1](https://aka.ms/aadrecoverykey "small")
[link 1](https://aka.ms/aadrecoverykey "medium")
[link 1](https://aka.ms/aadrecoverykey "big")
[link 2](http://myaccount.microsoft.com)
```

what I am trying to do is catch icon, small, medium or big keywords in quote marks in case it's there to maybe set size hints to resulting  tag. I am struggling to capture it conditionally. (ideally regex should match all test lines with 0-3 having additional capture group, 4th line not having that capture group at all because there is no hint specified.

I played around in regex generator but no luck capturing the group conditionally.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/c5b1kP/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change 2 things:

1. make the url match *reluctant* (ie `.*?`)
2. move the leading space and quotes around the hint type *inside* the conditional

This works for your examples:

```
\[(.*)]\((.*?)(?: \"(icon|small|medium|big)\")?\)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/ByIWwAHUHqxVLU).

---

Side note, you don't need to escape the `]`